# Are screenshots okay and edits changing intent

Tags: discussion, edits, images

This is partly a question, partly feedback about the editing process. I included a screenshot and caption in a question, and one editor removed them entirely. In addition, some other edits were made that (no doubt unintentionally) misrepresented my question (a fact noted by one editor who rejected the original edit). These were approved before I had a chance to review them and make corrections.

My first question is, are screenshots forbidden? I would usually not bother with it, but in this case, I sincerely felt the screenshot more clearly explained my question than mere text alone could, so it is a pity to have had it removed. I didn't replace it because I don't want to run afoul of the rule, but I do want to know the policy. I was able to correct the text.

The feedback is that this was not quite the experience that I think Stack Overflow is striving for. I have great respect for the curated nature of the questions here, and try always to live up to the standard, in my fashion. But in fact, I don't really know what one is to do if an editor changes the meaning of your question, or otherwise does something to your post that you don't understand, and you want to know more about what is behind their thinking. Unfortunately the "reason for edit" given was not explicit.

Comment: Screenshots of code, bad. Screenshots of expected or actual results (if graphical in nature) fine.

Comment: I like the edit that "fixed" *tiddler* to *toddler* ;) (To be clear, the reviewers of that one should be fired.)

Comment: Well, some people don't bother to check their work before sending. Even if one thinks (for whatever reason) that you meant "toddler", why only edit one and not all occurrences? There is not much you can do against it, only correct such mistakes when you notice them.

Comment: @yivi What if I had both?

Comment: If you had both types of screenshots: screenshots of code were useless and bad. Screenshots of expected or actual results (if graphical in nature) were fine.

Comment: "toddler" just made me laugh, but the fix for the admittedly unusual double "when" construction subtly changed my meaning and I tried to clarify it when I corrected it. The one that I regretted was the loss of the screen grab. I know I make mistakes, and heartily welcome edits...I am a proofreader myself, and I live by the rule of do no harm.

Comment: @yivi I meant, one screenshot that had some code and also showed the graphical results of the code in question.

Comment: Going by the version history, you seem to have added the image with an edit after posting. The editor probably didn't intentionally remove it, they just started editing the version from before you had it. Your screenshot looks fine to me.

Comment: Did your question include the problematic code as actual code, or was it present only in the screenshot? If the former, you should edit your screenshot to remove the code, since it's not relevant (as an image). If the latter, you should include your code or your question can be closed as "lacking an MCVE".

Comment: @TiiJ7 I see! Yes, that's right, I did add it as an afterthought. I feel better, thanks. In the end it's not a biggie but I much appreciate the clarification.

Comment: @yivi I understand your rationale as far as it might represent a slight duplication, but I don't quite it not being relevant. The image provides evidence that the same code is producing one result in one place and another elsewhere at the same time, and the caption says so. Excising the code (in addition to creating an unsightly image) would have made it harder for someone looking at it to understand at a glance what was happening...but with it, one glance tells you everything, and obviates doubt in the text. I defer to those of greater wisdom, naturally, but that would be my two cents...

Comment: @asllearner: I edited verboten to forbidden because I (as a native german speaker) thought it was a translation problem. I now noticed that the answer refers to it, so if you think that verboten should stay, feel free to rollback the edit.

Comment: “Verboten” sees limited usage in English as a German loan-word of the same meaning, probably because the pronunciation is so similar to “forbidden” in English, but it sounds...uh...smarter? cooler? different? @BDL

Comment: @BDL I was being cheeky is all. Easy come easy go. In my vernacular it is a ready locution, occasionally in the form "strictly verboten", where the mock german, though nowadays most often innocuously lighthearted (my intent), unfortunately by some of a politically correct bent might be claimed to have roots in some post-war anti-german sentiment. Consider the frequent overuse of it in the TV show Hogan's Heroes for example. So if you are offended, apologies. Do trust there was none of that in my response. I was just being playful, and trying to avoid the rather foreboding "forbidden".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[So this is the edit in contest](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55370648/3).

The edit adds an image of what I presume is the OP's current state, and could be seen to benefit anyone who is an expert at TiddlyWiki to help contextualize the situation.

In general, this falls in the use case of using an image to contextualize a visual result, which isn't *necessarily* something which can be derived from running the code.  **Its usage should be fine.**

But I'm going to be honest - I'm not *wild* about the image. They're not searchable in general, and can't be used by a screen reader to interpret or glean context.

However, I don't see a reason to *just* remove it and not actually address other structural concerns with the question, such as...making the phrasing flow a *little* bit clearer so that it's obvious what's being asked?

> ...what I really want is to put the tag (book) in a field and pull that

is buried underneath a lot of other things, and someone who isn't going to spend a lot of time reviewing this may not tease that out enough to argue that an edit which just removes the image is "sufficient".

So to answer your specific question - I don't see the image as being "bad" necessarily in this question.  I feel like there are other things which should be improved upon instead.

Comment: FWIW, the OP actually did include alt text when they added the image. It needed a little editing but it did describe the image.

Comment: I can’t tell if “contest” was a typo for “context” or not. Very nice.

Comment: @Makoto I have a peripatetic elocutionary style (much?). I am very open to improvements, and your comments are well taken. Some of the phrasing flow derives from the way the edit input screen stages the input of the answers. But I agree I buried the lead...always easier to spot in the rear view. I don't think I was really clear what I was asking, just that I had a problem ;-)

Comment: @Makoto and BSMP  I agree with what you said about images. I wrote the text to could stand alone. However I don't feel the image is superfluous, for the reasons you mentioned. I have a small feeling that Stack Overflow's edit policy does seem to have a slight bias towards doing only what is necessary, and eliminating every perceived redundancy or excess. I see the goal, but perhaps for a user like me, a slightly more nuanced policy would be more amenable.